# How does the OS find files in the file system?

Tags: filesystems, operating-systems, database

I'm curious about how an OS finds files in the file system.
For example I know in the FAT file system there is a DB of the files.

I know the OS finds files very fast, 
so I want to know if it
uses binary search to go through the FAT Database?
Or is there a faster method to do this?

and Is there a method for the OS to deduce the location of the files
in the file system straight away without searching the FAT Database?

Comment: This probably isn't the place to ask such a question. At best, we can get this migrated to the Programmers site.  But this is also very broad.  I'd suggest you google `linked lists` and `B tree`.

Comment: @TheCompWiz has summarized it anyway: *> The real question is... Why do you want to know... and what are you trying to accomplish? If you want more specific answers... give more specifics about what OS/platform/file-system you are talking about.*

Comment: I tried googling and wikipedia and there's a lot of information but not realy about the method the OS uses to find the file, but I understand that it's different for each OS and filesystem as you say so I'll try to post a more specific question probably in the Unix forum since I use linux.

Comment: The FAT does not list files; it is just an array of pointers, one for each cluster on the fs.  Each one points to the next cluster that logically follows this one in whatever file this one is a part of, or is one of several reserved values for things such as free/unused, end of file, and bad sectors.  Directories are what lists files, and they are linearly searched.

Comment: hmmm... so say I request from the OS a listing of files on the directory "/usr", how does it know the address of this directory on the HDD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly... this question has many answers... too many to enumerate here.  Largely this depends on the *type* of file-system... and the OS reading it... and also what features of the file-system are enabled.

Every file system has some sort of "database" as you described to translate a name/path to one or more locations on the disk.  How this "database" works is what makes each file-system different.  Some methods are better for some tasks than others.  Some are more recoverable & redundant in the event of a failure... some are strictly geared towards speed and have almost no recovery in the event of a single failure.

Depending on the OS, and the file-system type, the "database" can be partially or even completely loaded into RAM in order to help speed-up the process of locating the position on the disk.  Some file-systems make use of linked-lists & b-trees or other types of ordered trees in order to quickly locate files.  Journaling can also speed-up the read/write processes dramatically (given the right conditions).  There are even file-systems (mostly proprietary) that truly ARE a database.

The real question is... Why do you want to know... and what are you trying to accomplish?  If you want more specific answers... give more specifics about what OS/platform/file-system you are talking about.

Comment: I'm not trying to accomplish anything specific just get an image in my head of how the file systems usually work, I didn't realize there's such a difference. But I did mention the FAT file system in my post that can be used as an example since it's pretty common

Comment: Well... there are actually several variants on the FAT file system... but they all follow a similar structure.  If you want to get into the guts of it, here's a good read on FAT: http://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/ide/fat32.html  Unfortunately, a lot of that info might be waaaay overly complex for you... but at least it will point you in a direction.

Comment: Or even more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table

Comment: They first link was pretty good, thanx a lot.